Is there a way to know how much SOL is required to mint an NFT collection with 'x' items using sugar candy machine?
is there a way to know how much is fee to mint an NFT collection with 'x' items?
And is there a way to reduce fees?
I tried on devnet and it charges 0.022 sol for each NFT minting and creating with Metaplex sugar candy machine.

The cost of minting on devnet and mainnet are exactly the same.
Be aware that most of this cost is to store the nft data on chain so there is not really a way to get around it besides using different NFT standards.
E.g. metaplex bubblegum is cheapest. You can calculate the cost in compressed.app - bubblegum does not support candy machine though.
The middle ground probably would be using Metaplex Core, the latest NFT standard by metaplex. It is way cheaper than Token Metadata what you are trying to use (just 0. 0029 SOL per mint) and also has a candy machine implementation https://developers.metaplex.com/core-candy-machine

Yeah, i realised that minting in cNFTs are more cheaper than standart NFTs. Thanks for response it helps me well.
